# cannot start application with "npm start" in create-react-app project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

I've just installed create-react-app package globally and it worked just fine.
I'm working in Windows 10 environment inside the Windows Subsytem for Linux, so all coding is done inside my Ubuntu Linux.

After creating simple app I switched to the app folder and typed

```
npm start
```

and I got this error in my terminal

```
> helloworld@0.1.0 start <app path>
> react-scripts start
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module '../scripts/start'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.resolve (internal/module.js:18:19)
```

After some research I found that the problem here is with the react-scripts binary, exported in ./node-modules/.bin folder inside my app folder. When building node command string to run, react-scripts tries to resolve module's path as follows:

```
.concat(require.resolve('../scripts/' + script))
```

and node failed to resolve the path specified

I solved this simply with prepending the script path with the module's name:

```
.concat(require.resolve('react-scripts/scripts/' + script))
```

It seems that while in ./bin folder the script file "react-scripts.js" kind of outside any node module, so that the node engine cannot follow it's own algorithm:

```
    require(X) from module at path Y
    ...
      3. If X begins with './' or '/' or '../'
        a. LOAD_AS_FILE(Y + X)

    LOAD_AS_FILE(X)
      1. If X is a file, load X as JavaScript text.  STOP
```

So, the question is if it is something wrong with the create-react-app's predefined scripts or the problem is somewhere in my coding environment which does not fit well for create-react-app package?

Comment: Please share the exact commands you made from start to error, as well as the outputs/responses (maybe in a gist?). Did you run “npm install”? Did you specify you want to use npm instead of yarn? BTW, after creating the app it tells you what commands to run.

Comment: JBallin, I'll append info you asked for in my first message

Comment: The question is exhausted as I've tried to reproduce the problem from scratch completely deleting and recreating my app and the problem is gone. Everything just works.Strangely enough not worked the first time..